# How to create a GLib.TimeVal from timestamp?

Tags: application-development, indicator, python, glib

I have a value such as 'timestamp' below, where the last three digits correspond to milliseconds.

```
timestamp = 1340830988768
```

I currently have code that looks like the following:

```
import indicate
indicator = indicate.Indicator()
indicator.set_property_time("time", int(timestamp[:-3]))
```

I want to amend it to use:

```
from gi.repository import Indicate
indicator = Indicate.Indicator()
```

However, the new version of `set_property_time` requires the second parameter to be a `GLib.TimeVal`. How do I create a `GLib.TimeVal` from my timestamp? Millisecond precision is not important for this application.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with, maybe it is of any help:

```
>>> from gi.repository import GLib, Indicate
>>> timestamp = '1340830988768'
>>> indicator = Indicate.Indicator()
>>> timeval = GLib.TimeVal()
>>> timeval.tv_sec = int(timestamp[:-3])
>>> indicator.set_property_time("time", timeval)
>>>
```

Do note [this section](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html#GTimeVal) in the GLib reference manual:

> GLib is attempting to unify around the use of 64bit integers to represent microsecond-precision time. As such, this type will be removed from a future version of GLib.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I need, but I can't confirm until I fix some other issues with my code.